# android kernel syscall table hook

Tags: android, kernel-module, system-calls

I am using android 4.2.2(Jelly Been) with linux-kernel 3.0.31 source code. I am trying to hook open system call but i don't know that how to change a page from read-only to writable given an address because sys_call_table is read-only.
I have do it successfully on linux Ubuntu12.04 3.2.32 with lookup_address() function below.

```
int make_rw(unsigned long address)
   {
      unsigned int level;     
      pte_t *pte = lookup_address(address, &level);
      if(pte->pte &~ _PAGE_RW)
         pte->pte |= _PAGE_RW;
      return 0;
   }
```

but unfortunately this function is for x86 not for arm. I don't know how to do it on arm-arch

another way: based on write protect register

```
    #define CR0_WP 0x10000  //Write Protect Bit (CR0:16)
    unsigned long cr0;
    cr0 = read_cr0();
    write_cr0(cr0 & ~CR0_WP);/* remove write protection*/
    hookfunc(){...};  
    write_cr0(cr0);/* set write protection*/
```

but i do not know the relative register on arm-arch

Does there anyone have solved this problem?   waiting for answer online!

Comment: did you find how? I have the same problem.